# Building a RegEx, 12 letters without order, fixed number of individual letters

Tags: python, regex, string, match

I have a complex case where I can't get any further. The goal is to check a string via RegEx for the following conditions:

- Exactly 12 letters
- The letters W,S,I,O,B,A,R and H may only appear exactly once in the string
- The letters T and E may only occur exactly 2 times in the string.
- Important! The order must not matter

Example matches:

- WSITTOBAEERH
- HREEABOTTISW
- WSITOTBAEREH

My first attempt:

```
results = re.match(r"^W{1}S{1}I{1}T{2}O{1}B{1}A{1}E{2}R{1}H{1}$", word)
```

The problem with this first attempt is that it only matches if the order of the letters in the RegEx has been followed. That violates condition 4

My second attempt:

```
results = re.match(r"^[W{1}S{1}I{1}T{2}O{1}B{1}A{1}E{2}R{1}H{1}]{12}$", word)
```

The problem with trial two: Now the order no longer matters, but the exact number of individual letters is ignored.

I can only do the basics of RegEx so far and can't get any further here. If anyone has an idea what a regular expression looks like that fits the four rules mentioned above, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you _have_ to use regex, as opposed to just checking those conditions separately?

Comment: Why a regex? Can be done, but doesn't seem appropriate for this.

Comment: You need lookaheads, the regex may look like `^(?=[^W]*W[^W]*$)(?=[^S]*S[^S]*$)(?=[^T]*T[^T]*T[^T]*$)[A-Z]{12}$`

Comment: `may only appear exactly once` or `must`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility, although I still think regex is inappropriate for this. Checks that all letters appear the desired amount and that it's 12 letters total (so there's no room left for any more/other letters):

```
import re

for s in 'WSITTOBAEERH', 'HREEABOTTISW', 'WSITOTBAEREH':
    print(re.fullmatch('(?=.*W)(?=.*S)(?=.*I)(?=.*O)'
                       '(?=.*B)(?=.*A)(?=.*R)(?=.*H)'
                       '(?=.*T.*T)(?=.*E.*E).{12}', s))
```

Another, checking that none other than T and E appear twice, that none appear thrice, and that we have only the desired letters, 12 total:

```
import re

for s in 'WSITTOBAEERH', 'HREEABOTTISW', 'WSITOTBAEREH':
    print(re.fullmatch(r'(?!.*([^TE]).*\1)'
                       r'(?!.*(.).*\1.*\1)'
                       r'[WSIOBARHTE]{12}', s))
```

A simpler way:

```
for s in 'WSITTOBAEERH', 'HREEABOTTISW', 'WSITOTBAEREH':
    print(sorted(s) == sorted('WSIOBARHTTEE'))
```

Comment: This would allow multiple "W" (and others) and allows other characters than letters.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Please show a string that it matches which it shouldn't match.

Comment: Sorry, realised too late that the required letters are already 12.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I pointed it out now so it's perhaps clearer. I also feel like my second solution could maybe be shortened, like "none twice, except T/E are allowed once more". But I'm too sleepy now.

Comment: @Pychopath Shorter isn't always better if the regex becomes too hard to understand.